# how to group route by name in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-8

```php
Route::prefix('/admin/post')->middleware('admin')->name('admin.')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/all', [AdminPostController::class, 'index'])->name('post');
    Route::name('post.')->group(function(){
        Route::get('/create', [AdminPostController::class, 'create'])->name('create');
        Route::post('/store', [AdminPostController::class, 'store'])->name('store');
        Route::get('/{post:slug}/edit', [AdminPostController::class, 'edit'])->name('edit');
        Route::patch('/{post:slug}/update', [AdminPostController::class, 'update'])->name('update');
        Route::delete('/{post:slug}', [AdminPostController::class, 'destroy'])->name('delete');
    });
});
```

I am trying to group route by name but I don't know how can  I group

```
  Route::get('/all', [AdminPostController::class, 'index'])->name('post');
```

this route in this group

```
Route::prefix('/admin/post')->middleware('admin')->name('admin.')->group(function(){});
```

this group

I am trying to group route by name but I don't know how can  I group them

Comment: Could you explain what the exact problem you're facing is?  What you have should be working, unless you're facing an error or something else?

Comment: I am not facing an error but I am trying to group   Route::get('/all', [AdminPostController::class, 'index'])->name('post'); this route in below group

Comment: And why can't you?  What's wrong with simply moving it down two lines?

Comment: I try that but when I try to access like route('admin.post') it does not give me an url of that route

Comment: That's because, according to your rules, it would not be `admin.post` at that point; it would be `admin.post.post`

Comment: Oh! but I want to access it by calling like that. So how can I possibly do it?

Comment: The only difference between your outer group and your inner group is the addition of the name prefix, so your code should be left as-is if you just want to call the route by `admin.post`.  Unless of course your outer group has complexity that you haven't mentioned here.